# Spring data (JPARepository) + Ehcache 2nd level cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, jpa, ehcache

Has anyone worked with Spring data together with Ehcache second level cache? I have problems configuring it correctly.

JPA properties:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ad_lobby/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

Presistance unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Class is marked with Cacheable annotation

But when launching test:

```
@Test
public void testCache() {
def device = new Device()
deviceRepository.save(device)
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    long now = new Date().getTime()
    deviceRepository.findById(device.id)
    long dif = new Date().getTime() - now
    println('Difference: ' + dif)
}
}
```

I have 25 selects for my object, althought entity has been put in cache:

```
second level cache puts=1
second level cache hits=0
second level cache misses=0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you are using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, that will make your test method run in a single transaction. This basically means you are using a single session and the 2nd level cache isn't going to be hit, only the 1st level cache (the session itself).

Comment: Well I have found a solution and it works in my test case, will post it later.

Comment: Hmm maybe you are right, because I have changed my test: see it here (http://pastebin.com/3aMLHwvn ) but to make it work I must mark my methods in JpaRepository classes with @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}). Although I am not sure what works 2nd level cache or Query cache :|

Comment: That will enable query caching, or mark the query/results cacheable.

Comment: Yeah, I just think will query enabling is remembering result for this query or remembering entity globally

Comment: It caches the query result (for a query with the same parameters) optionally the entity can come from another part of the cache.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?